# Cannot mount Truecrypt volume after changing windows partition drive to dynamic

Tags: truecrypt

Big big problem I just put myself in. I was attempting to use windows disk manage to do a raid 1 for a truecrypt encrypted drive, but after restarting, the bootloader does not go past "booting..." and hangs. I originally set a basic disk to a dynamic disk as per instructed by microsoft.

I tried removing the harddrive to attach to another computer and try to mount the disk, but it currently shows "Disk 1: Dynamic Invalid" under disk management.

And attempting to mount states: "Wrong mount mode, incorrect password, or not a TrueCrypt volume"

I am all out of ideas and there are important files on the disk. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this old question and wondering - the boot loader on the disc is corrupt. You can load new bootloaders via the disc you made when you encrypted the system. Obviously you did actually make the disc and haven't lost it - that'd be silly.

Once you've loaded into the disc, you can add new bootloader to the drive and it should boot up. If not you can use the disc to slowly decrypt the drive and get it working that way.